# Genie Animation for WPF Window

Tags: c#, wpf, animation

I want to open a window on click of a button with animation such as

[image]

But instead of going inside the box I want it out of the box. I am able to find Genie effect with [Fluid Library](https://fluidkit.codeplex.com/) ([example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p9KENFOvgro)). But it works with GeometryModel3D.

I am unable to apply the same on window. Is there any library or sample app that does it for WPF window.

Comment: ["Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Challange accepted, but what u tried from ur side ?

Comment: @AnjumSKhan I have tried to add the Genie Animation in Fluid library to window. But the example given in the same uses Viewbox. I tried to put it on window, but I am not clear what will be target property and how we can assign the geometry point to window.

Comment: I am able to accomplish the content inside window as Genie animation, but I want to animate whole window
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gJEzDwELQKY